# React test; how to mock componentDidMount or overwrite it?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, mocking, reactjs

I'm trying to test a react component.

```js
var Component = React.createClass({

  componentDidMount: function () {

    return this.setState({
      name: 'blabla'
    });
  },

  render: function () {

    return (
      <h1>{this.state.name}</h1>
    );
  }
});
```

Is there a way, during testing, to mock what `componentDidMount` returns or does? That would leave me to test it on it's own and just test the component render behaviour.

Thanks!

Comment: You should not mock it. If you want to make sure your component works, mock everything you pass to it as a prop, mock all dependencies, but don't mock the component itself.

Comment: I disagree.  If OP is trying to write unit tests that test functions inside of his component, its not at all unusual for him to want to stub out other functions that might affect these tests.  OP - What testing framework are you using?  Depending on your answer, I might have a solution for you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. @MichaelParker I'm using karma and mocha.

Comment: Unfortunately, my solution will only work with Jasmine, so it does not apply to you if you are using Mocha.  If you would like, I can post it anyways.

Comment: @MichaelParker I don't mind switching to jasmine, I would appreciate if you can post your code:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea here, if I understand correctly, is that you're trying to stub out a function before a component is rendered in your test.  In your case, `componentWillMount` is only called once in a component's lifecycle, immediately before the component is rendered.  So you can't just render the component and **then** stub out the function, it must be done before the render occurs.

Let's take these components for example:

**parent.js**

```
var Child = require('./child.js');
var Parent = React.createClass({
    render : function () {
        return (
            <div className="parent">
                <Child/>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = Parent;
```

**child.js**

```
var Child = React.createClass({
    test : function () {
        return true;
    },
    render : function () {
        if (this.test) {
            throw('boom');
        }
        return (
            <div className="child">
                Child
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = Child;
```

Here, we would want to stub out the `test` function before our Child component is rendered, otherwise, it will blow up.

I have been able to do this using [jasmine-react](https://github.com/tommyh/jasmine-react).  These helper functions provide some useful functionality when running tests, almost to the point where `TestUtils` can be ditched completely.

`jasmineReact.render(component, [container])` will render an instance of `component` into the DOM node specified in `[container]`.  This is like `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument()`, except it renders the component into an attached DOM node instead of a detached DOM node.  It will also perform the necessary cleaning operations when the test is finished.

`jasmineReact.spyOnClass(componentClass, functionName)` will stub out a particular function belonging to a component class.  This behavior is maintained until the end of the test, which means that you can call this function **before** a component is rendered.  This, if I understand correctly, is what you're looking for.

So, using these two helper functions, I can write a test for the code shown above that looks something like this:

```
var React = require('react/addons'),
    Parent = require('./parent.js'),
    Child = require('./child.js'),
    jasmineReact = require('jasmine-react-helpers');

describe('Parent', function () {
    it('does not blow up when rendering', function () {
        jasmineReact.spyOnClass(Child, 'test').and.returnValue(false);
        var parentInstance = jasmineReact.render(<Parent/>, document.body); //does not blow up
        expect(parentInstance).toBeTruthy(); //passes
    });
});
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks for this! The `spyOnClass().and.returnValue()` looks amazing and pretty powerful!

Answer (score 6):

I prefer the following approach, but requires using ES6 classes.

```
// component.jsx
class Component extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() { return this.setState({name: 'blabla'}); }
    render() { return (<h1>{this.state.name}</h1>); }
}

//component-spec.jsx
describe('Component', () => {
    it('does stuff', () => {
        let ComponentTest = class extends Component {
            componentDidMount() { 
                // your override here
            }
        };
        let component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ComponentTest />);
        //expect(component...).toEqual(...)
    });
});
```

The point is to create an on demand ChildClass inheriting the OriginalClass,
do whatever overrides and then `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ChildClass />)`

Answer (score 1):

I've found two ways to go about this (i'm sure there are more).

1) I've used [sinon-chai](http://chaijs.com/plugins/sinon-chai) and required in the base element class and then use [rewireify](https://github.com/i-like-robots/rewireify) to put a set a spy on the `componentWillMount` method. This works but not sure what test suites you're using.

2) Probably the easier way. Is to just use the TestUtils to get an instance of the component and then just manually run the `componentWillMount` method.

That second way would probably look something like (forgive the pesudo code):

```
it('should call state when it first mounts', function () {
  var Component = require('../my-component');
  var component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<Component />);

  component.setState({name: null});
  component.componentWillMount();

  expect(component.state.name).to.equal('blabla');
});
```

Comment: Thanks @badAdviceGuy I will give it a go and let you know

Comment: Using `TestUtils.renderIntoDocument` will automatically trigger the `componentWillMount` function.  The first option looks promising though.

Comment: @MichaelParker, yes you're right the componentWillMount will automatically run, but then inside the test you reset the state and manually call the method again and then test the state again `component.componentWillMount()` etc.

Comment: Right, but if he wanted to stub it out so it didn't do anything, your second option would not work at all.  That was what I was trying to get at.